# How to call iCarte SDK methods for scanning RFID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nfc

I have iCarte Sdk which is used to read RFID tag values but i am not getting how to start with that sdk. i have set up my project according to the requirement of iCarte Sdk and i am able to get the hardware details using some methods provided in iCarte Sdk. But i am not getting how to initiate scanning the RFID tags. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation with the SDK? Are you telling us they gave you code and not a single bit of documentation on how to use it?

Comment: yes david i have read the documentation. There are some methods, but i am not getting how to start with those.

Comment: I have some interest in RFID for an application, so I just sent them a query on the SDK and device cost. I saw they have a tech support email - I suspect you will have more luck with it than here, as there cannot me more than a handful of people using that SDK on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and anyways i got it

Comment: Chakravarthy, how did you figure it out? I'm guessing it is a few lines of code to init, then call something like GetUID(ustr, &strSize)?
I would open a new question but I think mine is too similar to this and would just be a duplicate. Any help would be appreciated! (Especially the lines of code required to init and use Mifare1K().GetUID(ustr,8)

Comment: hey pierre, right now i dont have dat code with me. will provide you soon

Comment: I am also interested in this--also where did you purchase the iCarte and SDK?

Comment: sry i dont have idea, client provided that for me